# Dropdown is empty when using foreach from DB

Tags: database, foreach, dropdown

My program brings a list of a teacher from a table.
Then I want to show the names in the drop-down but for some reason, it opens an empty dropdown with the number of empty lines like the records in the table.
This is my code for this problem

```
    <div>
    <label for="teacher_name"> שם המורה:  </label>            
    <select name="teacher_name" id="teacher_name">
    <?php if (empty($teachers)): ?>
        <p> No teachers found</p>

    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if($status == 'new'): ?>
            <option value="please_select">נא לבחור</option>
            <?php foreach ($teachers as $teacher): ?>
                    
                <option value=<?=$teacher['teacher_name']; ?> name="teacher_name" id="teacher_name"></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?> 
        <?php endif; ?>   
            
            <?php if($status == 'edit'): ?>
                <p> edit</p>
                <input type="text" name="teacher_name" id="teacher_name"  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($lesson->teacher_name); ?>" >
            <?php endif; ?>                   
        <?php endif; ?>         
        </select>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you "view source" of your output I think you will see that the option tags do have data in them - but you haven't set the value to display, it should be more like `<option ....>Show this in the list</option>`.

Try this (the same code as you were using, but adding the teacher name variable again where it will display)

```
<option value=<?=$teacher['teacher_name']; ?> name="teacher_name" id="teacher_name"><?=$teacher['teacher_name']; ?></option>
```